# How do i convert sumifs in excel to a PowerBI formula?

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I am trying to replicate the following excel formula in PowerBi. It adds all the refunded costs from a Unique identifier between a date period

I have tried using the Sumx function in powerBi but It doesn't return the values i need it to return.

```
SUMIFS([@Refunded;
[@Date];">="&MAX([@Date])-42;
[@Date];"<="&MAX([@Date])-14;
[@UID];)
```

It needs to return the sum of the same unique identifiers between 42 and 14 days earlier.

I have tried solving is as follows:

```
calculate(SUM([Refunded]),DATESBETWEEN(all_funnel_data_view[Date].[Date],Value(all_funnel_data_view[Date].[Date])=TODAY()-42,Value(all_funnel_data_view[Date].[Date])=TODAY()-14))
```

But is only returns empty field

Answer (score 0):

Use the `FILTER` function as the second argument of `CALCULATE`.  In this, you can filter the date column of the `all_funnel_data_view` table for a date in the specified time frame.  I'm assuming that `Refunded` is a column, not already a measure.  If so, qualifying it with the name of the table will help to make the measure easier to read.  In the following example, "YourFactTable" is used for this.

```
CALCULATE
    (
    SUM(YourFactTable[Refunded]),
    FILTER(all_funnel_data_view, 
            AND
                (
                all_funnel_data_view[date] >= TODAY() - 42,
                all_funnel_data_view[date] <= TODAY() - 14
                )
            )
        )
```